# which data type can save bangla Language in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save bangla Language in sql server. Using which data type I can Do it in sql server 2005 or sql server 2008.

I tried varchar and varbinary type but it cannot save bangla Language.

How is it possible?

Comment: What coallation are you using?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 5):

You're using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` for your collation, which is suited for the Latin character set (ISO-8859-1). To store characters fromother character sets, you can use the `NVARCHAR()` which can store the full Unicode range, irrespective of collation - this does mean it will need to be treated as `NVARCHAR()` all the way, as quoted constants (e.g. `N'বাংলা Bangla'`), as the data types for parameters to stored procedures, etc.